# Best way to develop application with multiple instances in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I Am working on one AWS  POC, it uses different aws component, below are the details of each individual components.

1- java function have code to generate data, I am calling it from lambda function through cloud watch scheduler

2- datapipe-line to copy data from RDS to S3.

3- Run hive scripts using athena over s3 data.

4- quicksight for visualization.

I am done with creating individual model but not able to understand what could be best way to connect all these components,So it can run in one go.

one though is to use lambda as a connector for each step. but have no template to connect lamda with Athena.

Kindly anyone can suggest best way to connect all above component.So that it can run in one go.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with hive scripts or quicksight, but a cloudformation stack or a terraform stack should assist you to connect various aws components as your workflow demands.